# Filtering on PagedCollectionView causes problems in combination with DataForm

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I am developing a Silverlight application which contains a page that looks like this:

```
    --------------------------------
    |          |                   |
    | DataGrid:| DataForm:         |
    |  list of |  selected         |
    |  objects |  object's details |
    |          |                   |
    --------------------------------
```

The user selects an object from the DataGrid and that object's details are displayed and can be edited in the DataForm on the right side.

Both the DataGrid and the DataForm bind to the same `PagedCollectionView`.

If I don't apply a Filter to this PagedCollectionView, everything is fine. However, when I apply a filter and then try to edit and save an object's details, a NullReferenceException occurs somewhere in the `RaisePropertyChanged` function that fires the PropertyChanged event of the object that is being edited. This exception originates from `DataForm.OnCurrentItemPropertyChanged` and is caused by the fact that the DataForm's CurrentItem is suddenly `null`.

What causes this bug, and how can I avoid it?

#### UPDATE: a workaround

A workaround to avoid this issue: in the object that is being edited, instead of calling `RaisePropertyChanged` immediately when a property's value is changed, I call this method with a delay of 100ms. This way, the DataForm and PCV can work their magic and only after they have finished, the RaisePropertyChanged calls are executed.

This probably somehow prevents some timing / synchronisation issues between the PCV the DataForm, and the object that is being edited, but I feel dirty for even typing this workaround :) Can anybody use this information to figure out what is the problem?

#### XAML

```
<controls:DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsPCV}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    IsReadOnly="True">

<controls:DataForm 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsPCV}" 
    AutoGenerateFields="False" 
    AutoEdit="False" 
    AutoCommit="False"
    CommandButtonsVisibility="Add, Edit, Navigation, Commit, Cancel">
```

Comment: Are you element-binding the form directly to your datagrid current item? Can you provide the Xaml to review?

Comment: @HiTechMagic - The PagedCollectionView tracks the current item for me, I do not need to bind this explicitly. In fact, I have tried to bind the selected item of both the DataGrid and DataForm to the same property of my ViewModel, but that makes no difference.